# Get domain Name from IP

Tags: c++, sockets

How can I get domain name from IP address. Is it possible? What functions do I have to use?

```
enter code herestruct sockaddr_in saGNI;
char hostname[NI_MAXHOST];
char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV];
u_short port = 443;

saGNI.sin_family = AF_INET;
saGNI.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.87.9");
saGNI.sin_port = htons(443);

// Call getnameinfo
int ok = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &saGNI,
             sizeof (struct sockaddr),
             hostname,
             NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, NI_MAXSERV, 0);

return hostname;
```

ok = 0, hostname = 74.125.87.9

I really dont know.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be none, one or many domain names associated with a give IP address.

Comment: for testing purposes, i want all the domain names asociated with ip

Comment: try passing NI_NUMERICSERV as flag instead 0. From my man:    **NI_NUMERICSERV:** If  set,  then  the  numeric  form  of  the  service address is returned.  (When not set, this will still  happen in  case  the service's name cannot be determined.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible because multiple domains/subdomains can point to the same IP address.

For instance, on my site, I have a dedicated IP, however I use the same server with that IP to host multiple web sites as well as subdomains, so if you will try to get the domain name, how will it know what domain to return?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: actually, there is special reverse DNS lookup zone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup

Comment: In the section "Multiple pointer records" it says doing DNS reverse lookup with shared IP address can cause issues, so doesn't it mean that DNS reverse loop up is not reliable tool?

Comment: Sure it is not reliable. It's up to IP address owner to create reverse ARP records correctly and to create it at all. If I had been delegated reverse ARP zone for any address I can make it resolve to 'stackoverflow.com'. If you look at reverse dns for 207.46.197.32 (microsoft.com) with host -t ptr 32.197.46.207.in-addr.arpa, you could see two thousand(!) reverse entries for different domains.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [GetHostByAddr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is deprecated) or the newer [GetNameInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They work with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: i tried but it doesnt resolve domain name or i couldnt make it, can you please post working example?

Comment: @Rampage: I used only GetAddrInfo(), so I can't guarantee. This code is directly from the MSDN: http://pastebin.com/QQfi6GMi

Comment: getNameInfo works :) but, what happens if there are more domains?

Comment: @Rampage: Neither the MSND and my man provide this possibility. I don't know how to help you, but I'm googling around for this. :)

Comment: @Rampage: probably there could be more domain name associated to a single ip, but getnameinfo allows you to specify the port too, and probably only one domain name is associated with a particular combination ip:port. So you shouldn't have this kind of problem if you know both ip and port.

Comment: for some ips it works but not for every(i know that it has its domain name), i am so desperate...

Comment: @Rampage: do you know the port too?

Comment: for example https://www.google.com i know its ip and port and when i call getnameinfo, it doesnt return google.com but only the same ip as i posted to this func

Comment: @Rampage: perhaps there are some errors (in this case getnameinfo returns something != 0)

Comment: Can you get the domain name using nslookup?

Comment: if i use nslookup with domain name, it returns ip, but when i use nslookup with ip, it never returns domain

Comment: voting down for providing answer only for Windows.

Comment: Rampage :- Do you got the answer? I am also facing same problem getnameinfo function not retriving the full name(with domain name) for other domain for same domain its working( retriving complete name.) Please help..

Comment: I doesn't work because our ip address is never linked to a domain name but your domain name is. If you try to use ```getnameinfo```, you will get the hostname of socket the address is binded to with either the port in the form if string or the service name. Whenever a domain name is used, it is replaced by its ip address and then any other operation like connection, sending or recieving is done.

Answer (score -2):

You can use following [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getnameinfo.html) - some useful information inside. They use

```
int getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr *restrict sa, socklen_t salen,
       char *restrict node, socklen_t nodelen, char *restrict service,
       socklen_t servicelen, int flags);
```